# Left Join to attach same table with date range

Tags: mysql

I have an expense table that I'm trying to pull multiple calculated values from. I've started here with the easiest which is "today". My goal is to query the data I need from the table with it's respective related tables then to also query the same parent table with different date ranges. I have a query for this but the results of `todaytotal` aren't correct...am I calculating the date wrong some how or missing something critical? Thanks!

**the whole thing**

```
SELECT e.id AS exid, SUM(e.amount) AS grandtotal, e.note, e.edate, e.x1id, e.x5id, e.type, e.CreateDate, e.CreateID, e.CreateIP, 
r.name AS typename, u.fname, u.lname, ev.name as eventname, SUM(etoday.amount) AS todaytotal
FROM 08_00_main e /* expense table */

LEFT JOIN 08_00_main etoday /* should only contain values with todays date */
ON DATE(etoday.edate) = DATE(NOW())

LEFT JOIN 98_00_main r /* reference table with the names of the expense types */
ON r.parid = 16
AND r.tier = 3
AND r.intid = e.type

LEFT JOIN 01_00_main u /* user table */
ON u.id = e.x1id

LEFT JOIN 05_00_main ev /* events table - expenses can be linked to an event */
ON ev.id = e.x5id

WHERE e.active = 1

GROUP BY e.type
ORDER BY e.type
```

**EDIT**
Adding my results/layout for easier understanding

Here's the table as it sits, base data, before query.
[image]

And here's what the query above returns
[image]

Comment: Your query is gruping by every field that is not included in `aggregate` function, not only your column `type`. That might be the reason why you are getting different results than expected in `todaytotal`. For further assistance some data, current and expected output would be of a great help.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I follow though...I tried switching it up a little but still no luck. I've added some images to make it easier to understand what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem since this effectively joins every row of e with row 4 of etoday:

```
LEFT JOIN 08_00_main etoday /* should only contain values with todays date */
ON DATE(etoday.edate) = DATE(NOW())
```

I think you want to do this instead:

```
LEFT JOIN 08_00_main etoday /* should only contain values with todays date */
ON DATE(etoday.edate) = DATE(NOW()) AND etoday.id = e.id
```

Comment: You are 100% correct. Thank you! Flipping genius answer. I wasn't thinking it through. You're my hero today. Thank you again!